# Can't start Eclipse IDE in my system

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

i have Eclipse indigo ide today i updated through eclipse market place a added `SpringSource Tool Suite (STS)` ide downloaded required files and asked like `restart` i restart the eclipse but it giving error like

`[image]

in that liog file one Exception is like this

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-02-05 15:19:06.515
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

so how to fix this ????

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have problems with the `eclipse.core.runtime` i would reinstall the IDE.